# Clickhouse database - backup - replica has part different from part on another replica - inconsistencies between the shards

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-backup

While taking backup of clickhouse, it throws exception about inconsistencies between parts in different shards in different replica.

```sql
BACKUP DATABASE default 
ON CLUSTER 'cluster-name' 
TO S3(
    'https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/clickhouse_backup/backup-2023_08_24'
)
```

If there are inconsistent data between shards, it throws exception like this :

```bash
Table default.`test_local` on replica 
chi-xxx-yyy-2-1 has part all_0_5_1 different from the part on replica chi-xxx-yyy-1-0 
(checksum '458fcabc38e861c2db258fe4dc6a412b' on replica chi-xxx-yyy-2-1 != checksum '65908f2583cad89f528bbfc4893dc779' on replica chi-xxx-yyy-1-0).
(CANNOT_BACKUP_TABLE)
```

I tried to use `SYSTEM` commands related to `REPLICA` but here is the status :

```sql
-- fails saying Replica must be readonly
SYSTEM RESTORE REPLICA test_local ON CLUSTER 'cluster-name';

-- this ran successfully but didn't fix the replica
SYSTEM RESTART REPLICA ON CLUSTER 'cluster-name' test_local;

-- this ran successfully but didn't fix the replica
SYSTEM SYNC REPLICA ON CLUSTER 'cluster-name' test_local STRICT;
```

Tech stack:

- Clickhouse version : 23.6.2
- Zookeeper version : 3.7.1
- Number of shards : 3
- Number of replicas : 3

I tried with single replica. Still I found there were inconsistent parts in different shards.

- How do we resolve this issue and bring the parts in different shard in different replica to consistent state ?
- How parts in different shards end up having different

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: No., It's still open